# UIView scrolling vertical when it shouldn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm having some strange behaviour. I have a UIScrollView setup in the interface builder. I have this code:

```
    //set up scrollview
    UIView *content = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SelectStickerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(620 ,155);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:content];
```

for some reason it is scrolling vertically now, but the content size is set to exactly the same as the content UIView size. It works fine in my other UIViewController but not on this one! Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: I don't have any constraints or anything set no

Comment: You don't have to add constraints. Is the checkbox check?

Comment: it's enabled yes, but it's also enabled for my other view controller and it works fine in that.

Comment: Does the other one has the scroll view in the xib or you're adding it as a subview programmatically?

Comment: scrollview in a xib exactly like the one above. it's so strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71697/discussion-between-ashraf-tawfeeq-and-kex).

Comment: When the **content size** is the same as the **scroll view size**, it won't scroll. If your content size is bigger than the scroll view size, it will scroll. Scrolling is not dependent on the `scrollView.contentSize` being the same as its contained view's size.

Comment: @IanMacDonald my content size is bigger than the scrollView size. The scrollView size is 155x155 and the content is 620x155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and want to post the answer in case it's useful for someone else. I added:

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

and it fixed the problem. It works fine in my other UIViewController without this line, maybe it's something to do with the auto layout but I guess if you always use this line you can cover your bases. Cheers guys